# Lowering polycount of OSRS enviroment to use in Roblox studio

Tags: mesh, modifiers, faces

I am a first time blender user attempting to port the location of Lumbridge from Oldschool Runescape into Roblox Studio. 
There's a tool: https://github.com/ConnorDY/OSRS-Environment-Exporter that exports a location chunk from the game into a gltf file.
I can import this straight into roblox but the mesh has too many polygons for robloxs' limit so it decreases the quality majorly and makes it look very bad. In Blender I have tried using decimate to lower the polygon count but it deletes the important little details like cannons on the castle and grass. Is there any other way to lower the polycount of the mesh so I can import it? Any help appreciated thank you.

Comment: split the scene into multiple files that don't exceed 20k triangles